# Question: How do I fix these overlapping freestyle lines?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

So I am trying to make this scene with a helicopter flying through a city with a filter that looks like its still a cartoon (AKA Freestyle lines), and since I am fairly new to Blender Render, I have tried messing with the settings on the freestyle lines and was wondering what settings do I put it on so that only the helicopter's lines are in front and the back buildings aren't showing in this scene?

Does anyone have any sugesstions on the settings I need?
Below are images of my settings I have as well as a screenshot of the problem.

My settings:

[image]

My scene:

[image]